# Data grid with editable fields and adding row facility

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

is there any of plugins that can help me on displaying daa on a table as well as edit it on runtime which helps to add new row automatically same like ms access table

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried handsontable.com Source code available from https://github.com/warpech/jquery-handsontable

```
<script src="../lib/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="dist/jquery.handsontable.full.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="dist/jquery.handsontable.full.css">

<div id="dataTable"></div>
<script>
  var data = [
    ["", "Kia", "Nissan", "Toyota", "Honda"],
    ["2008", 10, 11, 12, 13],
    ["2009", 20, 11, 14, 13],
    ["2010", 30, 15, 12, 13]
  ];
  $("#dataTable").handsontable({
    data: data,
    startRows: 6,
    startCols: 8
  });
</script>
```

Comment: thank you very much sir but i am stuck on new problem... i just want all column labels to mine own lables... is that possible on this plugin????

Comment: also to edit or add any record i should double click on it in fact i would like to write any data on it like excel... is this too possible???

Comment: its kind like awkward asking you lots of question but... i am using it for the first time so i would like to know that is it possible that data written on this grid can be posted on mysql database?

Comment: Set your column headings in the first row of the javascript object `"", "Kia", "Nissan", "Toyota", "Honda"` Single click editing is unlikely to work because it's possible to select multiple cells and single clicking would probably interfere with that. Saving the contents of the table is possible with ajax, look here: http://handsontable.com/demo/ajax.html

Comment: sorry sir but yesterday i didn't see all the demos, and yes there's a provision for changing colheaders to own
$("#dataTable").handsontable({
    data: data,
    startRows: 6,
    startCols: 8
    colHeaders: ['Serial No', 'First Name', 'Last Name', 'Gender', 'Date of Birth'],
  });